# Preserve XML Tags - Python DOM Implementation

Tags: python, xml, dom

I have just finished skiming through the [python DOM API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) and can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I basically want to preserve the XML tags when traversing through the DOM tree. The idea is to print the tag name and corresponding attributes which I later want to convert into an xml file.

```
<book name="bookname" source="/home/phiri/Book/book.xml"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <chapter>
    <page>page1</page>
    <page>page2</page>
  </chapter>
  <chapter>
    <page>page1</page>
    <page>page2</page>
    <page>Page3</page>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

Using the XML contents above for instance, what I want is for the result of the book.xml file to have.

```
<book name="bookname" source="/home/phiri/Book/book.xml"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <chapter></chapter>
  <chapter></chapter>
</book>
```

Is there an alternative xml package I could use to preserve results I get when extracting contents using python?

Comment: The question isn't very clear.. it sounds like you want to use XSLT (stylesheet transforms). You'll be more likely to get help if you clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SteveMc: Thank you for responding. I am basically trying to break down my XML document into smaller pieces with only two levels each.

Book.xml will have book nodes and chapter nodes
chapter.xml will have chapter nodes and page nodes
page.xml will just have page number text

I hope that helps clarify things.

Comment: The Idea is to eventually reassemble the complete document using XInclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get the output you posted from the input is to override the [XSLT identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).  It looks like you want to eliminate all text nodes and all elements that have more than two ancestors, so you'd just add empty templates for those:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template match="*[count(ancestor::*) &gt; 2]"/>
```

Generally the best way to use XSLT in Python is with the [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) module.  Unless you need a pure Python solution, in which case you're stuck not using XSLT, because nobody's built a pure Python XSLT processor yet.

Comment: Thank you; I suppose I will have to stick to XSLT then.